# Past Simple and Past Perfect. "I had seen" or "I saw" him a few days before he left

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-continuous

Yesterday I saw this sentence in some test without any context:
I ... (see) him a few days before he ... (leave).
My answer was "I'd seen him a few days before he left", but it was wrong. 
Right answer was "I saw him a few days before he left". 
I understand that the second answer is also correct, but I don't think I'm wrong, or am I?

Comment: If you want to use perfect tenses, you should be able to state why. Otherwise, it may be best not to use them (from a learners perspective anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I **saw** him a few days before he left.

In this example without additional context, it is understood that you "saw him" on one occasion, a few days ago. Therefore, past tense is sufficient.

> I **had seen** him a few times before he left.

Here past perfect is OK because you "saw him" over a period of time in the past.

Answer (score -1):

The PAST PERFECT TENSE indicates that an action was completed at some point in the past before something else happened.

For example : "The patient had died before the doctor came", let's understand this using a practical example,
let's say the patient died at 5 PM then the doctor would have come after 5 PM.

So in your example if you say " I had seen him a few days before he left", this means that you saw him before he even left which is incorrect, that's why the correct answer was "I saw him a few days before he left".